# Finding k th smallest number in BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is a recursive Solution:-

```
 private static int INDEX = 0;

 public static void findKthSmallest(Node node) { 

  if (node == null) {
   System.out.println("Tree is empty!!");
   return;
  } 


  if (node.left != null) {
      findKthSmallesRecursive(node.left);
  }

  ++INDEX;

  if (K == INDEX) {
   System.out.println("Kth Smallest Node Value: " + node.data);
   return;
  }  

  if (node.right != null) {
      findKthSmallesRecursive(node.right);
  }

 }
```

If the tree is :-

```
   10
   /
  5
 /
2
```

Let say k is 2
The 2nd smallest element will be = 5.

1st recursive call: `findkthSmallest(10)` which calls `findkthsmallest (5)` which then calls `findkthsmallest (2)`. Now I am getting confused how the recursive call is processed back from this point. and give the desired output. The code runs fine and gives expected result.

Comment: Where is `K` declared?

Comment: `public static void findKthSmallest(Node node) {`  There's no K parameter to this function

Comment: Shouldn't the find method *return* the value rather than updating a *static* field?

Comment: run inorder traversal and it will sort in ascending order and get k element out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you  mean K=Level in BST and pass them to method.
When (2 == INDEX ) is satisfied , the recursion stops there with return statements printing the desired result. 
It backtracks to its callers but since there are no ops defined over returned values it just backtracks until its reaches its original level of triggering the recursion

Answer (score 0):

The code is traversing the tree in inorder way; i.e. it goes to left child first and then root and then to right child.

Also after visiting left subtree of a particular node, it increment the index and checks if it is equal to k;If yes then it is the target node;

Since all the nodes in left sub-tree of a particular node will always be less than the node; and the whole left sub-tree is being processed before that particular parent node; and the index variable is being incremented while processing a node; so Up-to the K-th minimum node, the index variable will keep correct results but as soon as you will get k-th minimum node, It will skip all elements present in its right sub-tree and the control will be passed to parent node which will continue processing its right sub-tree without knowing the number of nodes present in the sub-tree that was skipped by its left child.

To make it more simple lets work with the example you mentioned:

```
Lets define the whole code as a 4 step process:

a. Check the left child and process if it exists.

b. Increment the value of index.

c. Check if the index is equal to k and return if yes.

d. Check the right child and process if it exists.




  We begin with root node i.e. 10:

    1.a. findKthSmallest(10) calls findKthSmallest(5) as its left is not null.

    2.a. findKthSmallest(5) calls findKthSmallest(2) as its left is not null.

    3.a. findKthSmallest(2) cant call its left as it does not have any left child.

    3.b. Index is incremented for Node 2 . Now index=1.

    3.c. Is index==k ?? No, so proceed to step d.

    3.d. findKthSmallest(2) cant call its right as it does not have any right child.

    2.b. Index is incremented for node 5. Now index=2.

    2.c. Is index==k ?? Yes, So don't run step d and return.

    1.b. Index is incremented for Node 2 . Now index=3.

    1.c. Is index==k ?? No, so proceed to step d.

    1.d. findKthSmallest(2) cant call its right as it does not have any right child.
```

Answer (score 0):

Like all recursion*, the call stack contains the control for your operations as the recursive calls start to return - program control is returned to the point where your current_node pointer is set to the parent that you were examining prior to making the recursive calls.

```
(* All recursion, unless there's tail-call optimization going on, in which case it is just a loop).
```

When you recurse, or have a function call itself, the arguments will change each time.  In the case of traversing a binary search tree, each recursive call has a different node of the binary tree as an argument.

The initial function call is given the head node of the binary search tree.  That node has a value.  If the value is equal to what value you're looking for, you found it and can return true.  If it's greater, then you know, if you have any chance of finding your value, it will be in the left portion of the tree, so you recursively call the same function, passing the left child node as the new argument.  Otherwise (the node's value is less than your target) use the right child node.  If you want to recursively call using a child node but there is no child node, then you've reached the end of your search and can return false.

Example of BST:

[image]

***Explanation:***
A `"binary search tree" (BST) or "ordered binary tree"` is a type of binary tree where the nodes are arranged in order: for each node, all elements in its `left subtree` are `less-or-equal to the node (<=)`, and all the elements in its right subtree are greater than the `node (>)`. The tree shown above is a binary search tree -- the `"root" node is a 5`, and its `left subtree nodes (1, 3, 4) are <= 5`, and its `right subtree nodes (6, 9) are > 5`. Recursively, each of the subtrees must also obey the binary search tree constraint: in the `(1, 3, 4) subtree`, the 3 is the root, the `1 <= 3 and 4 > 3`. Watch out for the exact wording in the problems -- a "binary search tree" is different from a "binary tree".

The nodes at the bottom edge of the tree have empty subtrees and are called "leaf" nodes (1, 4, 6) while the others are "internal" nodes (3, 5, 9).

For Details, You can follow [BST](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/110/BinaryTrees.html)